# incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double

Tags: java

```
String LOA, LWL, Beam, Displacement, SailArea;
LOA = stdin.readLine(); //(LOA) Total Length of Vessel
System.out.println("LOA: " + (LOA));
System.out.println("HullSpeed: " + (1.34 * Math.pow(LWL, 0.5)));
```

Can I get help? I'm new to java and have no idea how to fix this error with the last LWL.
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double

Comment: What is the value of `LWL`?

Comment: is there a way to use while or for loops?

Answer (score 5):

If `LWL` is a `String` that represents a `Double`, try parsing that `Double` by using [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Double LWLDouble = Double.parseDouble(LWL);
System.out.println("HullSpeed: " + (1.34 * Math.pow(LWLDouble, 0.5)));
```

It's reasonable that you can not use a mathematical operations on a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

See this part of your code,

```
System.out.println("HullSpeed: " + (1.34 * Math.pow(LWL, 0.5)));
```

Here, LWL is of `String` type `Math.pow()` does not take a `String` argument it takes a `double`.

More on types in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm)